# Give an example of an isometry which is not surjective.

Tags: functional-analysis

I know the definition of an isometry and surjective also. But i don't know such type of example.

Comment: You're question isn't very clear but any rotation in the plane is a surjective isometry from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Just because of the tag "functional analysis" I presume you mean a linear isometry of a normed linear space. (You should edit your question to say this; isometry has a more general meaning.)

Answer (score 8):

In finite dimensions, it's impossible, since isometries are injective and injectivity of operators implies surjectivity. You need to go to infinite dimensions to get an example. A simple one is the right shift operator:
$$T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2 : (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) \mapsto (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$$
where $\ell^2$ is equipped with its usual (inner product) norm. We have,
\begin{align*}
\|(x_1, x_2, x_ 3, \ldots)\| &= \sqrt{|x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + |x_3|^2 + \ldots} \\
\|(0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)\| &= \sqrt{0^2 + |x_1|^2 + |x_2|^2 + \ldots},
\end{align*}
which are equal, hence $T$ is an isometry. It's not surjective because $(1, 0, 0, \ldots)$ is not in the range.

Comment: Note same construction, the right shift,  works in all the classical sequence spaces, $\def\ell{\mathcal l}$  $\ell^1, \ell^2,  \ell^p, \ell^\infty$.